# WordPress Gutenberg View Post From Editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I don't know if I'm being dense, but I can't see how to view a post from the Gutenberg editor without either editing it first and updating,  or manually changing the URL.

They don't hate us that much do they?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The editor is in [full-screen mode by default](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/22178) and hides the top toolbar that displays the view page button.
You can [disable the full-screen mode](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/handbook/faq/#editor-shortcuts) by `CMD (or control) +Option+Shift+F`     or `⇧⌥⌘F` or by opening the 3 dot button in the upper-right hand corner of your screen.